# Amchart : Disable natural time scaling

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts, amcharts4

I have a list of date that gap 7 day each point, but the chart are auto creating more date point , so the chart result look messy. So I searching all the doc of Amcharts and found this [Natural time scale](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/date-axis/#Natural_time_scale). However I could not find any related doc about to disable this.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable this by setting [`skipEmptyPeriods`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/dateaxis/#skipEmptyPeriods_property) to true, as mentioned [further down the very same page you linked to](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/date-axis/#Removing_empty_time_units)

```
dateAxis.skipEmptyPeriods = true;
```